# Measures of randomness of graphs

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, random, random-graphs

[There are many practical measures of randomness for binary or number sequences.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomness_test#Specific_tests_for_randomness) Some randomness tests yield a single number (like [Kolmogorov complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity)), others come as batteries of tests (like the [diehard tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diehard_tests)). These randomness tests may supposedly not be applied to graphs (given as binary adjacency matrices), at least not in a straight forward way. This is because each permutated adjacency matrix (yielding a different binary sequence) must have the same degree of randomness.

I am looking for a concise overview over "direct" measures of randomness of graphs.

Comment: Since you mention it, you could represent a graph with its adjacency matrix and then compute the Kolmogorov complexity of the adjacency matrix.

Comment: @John_Krampf: By arbitrary permutations one can make the strictly ordered adjacency matrix of - say - a circle or grid graph into a seemingly random matrix resp. binary sequence. How would Kolmogorov check this - and not the randomness of the permutation?

Comment: There are two ways to go around that : brute force, and canon.
Brute force would be : generate every permutation of the adjacency matrix, find the smallest in (typically) lexicographic order, and give that one to the Kolmogorov complexity.
Canon would be : choose one canonical way to order the vertices in the graph, and always use it. This might give a little better results in Kolmogorov complexity because sometimes that canonical representation might be more natural (and simple) than the lexicographically smallest one ; but you have to be sure about your represenation being unique.

Comment: The brute force can be even more brutal : you generate every permutation, sort them by lexicographic order, and then concatenate them. This way you're a little more sure that the program generating the sequence has some understanding of the symmetry through permutation of the vertices.

Comment: @HugoManet: Why not simply generate every permutation, compute its Kolmogorov complexity, and choose the smallest Kolmogorov complexity?

Comment: @HugoManet: But because this is not feasible for large graphs, this is not the kind of practical measure I am looking for. If one would say, that there can be no measure as accurate as Kolmogorov complexity, we would have a problem: every practical measure would partly be inaccurate.

Comment: Every permutation of the adjacency matrix is one permutation away (which is quite small for Kolmogorov complexity) from another, so it wouldn't matter. But yeah, it works.
None of this is practical anyway. If you want a practical measure, it's probably because you have an application in mind where you need randomness ; and thus you should design the test with that application in mind...

Comment: look up pseudorandomness for graphs

Answer (score 1):

As you probably know, the question you ask is crucial in many random graph generation methods.

Indeed, many of them start with a given (biased) graph in a class of interest and perform random small rearrangements of edges that *mix* the graph and are known to *ultimately* lead to a uniformly distributed random graph the given class.

A typical example is edge swap (replace $u-v$ and $u'-v'$ by $u-v'$ and $u'-v$) under constraints (not creating loops nor multi-edges) in order to generate random *simple* graphs. See the following paper for more: [Generating constrained random graphs using multiple edge switches](https://arxiv.org/abs/1012.3023) by Lionel Tabourier, Camille Roth, Jean-Philippe Cointet.

Unfortunately, in most cases, the number of local rearrangements needed to reach uniform distribution is huge, and, even worse, *unknown*. Therefore, one then resorts to make *many* rearrangements and hope this is *enough*. This is where your question is crucial: how do we know we made *enough* rearrangements?

Well, people usually make as many as they can, and plot basic statistics of the obtained graphs, as a function of the number of rearrangements (there are several examples in the paper above). If the statistics converges to a steady value, then one assumes that the graph is *random regarding this statistics*. One may also use an estimate of the expected value of the statistics (when available), and check that the mixing reached a value close to this expected value... but this remains very empirical.

I fear this does not answer your question, but this shows that **there is certainly no (known) way to have a formally grounded but practical randomness test for graphs, in general**.

Maybe this is possible in some restricted classes?

I suggest you ask on MathOverflow.